# How to make a MessageBox show during a .NET build?

Tags: c#, .net

I use a 3rd party control that (if not licensed) shows a dialog box when building a project that references their dll.  Although this is super annoying, it made me wonder how they did that?  Any ideas?

Comment: Can we have a reference to this control?

Comment: The product is http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using the standard MS licensing infrastructure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe8b1eh9(VS.71).aspx